# dimension problem on replacing for loops with foreach in R

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I have the following (very simplified) loop setting:

```
res <- array(0, c(4, 3, 2))

for (i in 1:4) {
    for (j in 1:3) {
      res[i,j,] <-   c(i,j) # this is not the vector I have, it should just demonstrate the dimensions. In my case there is a matrix multuplication with %*%
    }
  }
```

which gives me the following output:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    2    3
[3,]    1    2    3
[4,]    1    2    3
```

Now, what I want is to run the same thing parallel with two foreach loops. But my attempt:

```
res2 <- foreach(i=1:4, .combine='rbind') %dopar% {
  foreach(j=1:3 , .combine='c')%do% {
    c(i,j)
  }
}
```

gives me the wrong output:

```
result.1    1    1    1    2    1    3
result.2    2    1    2    2    2    3
result.3    3    1    3    2    3    3
result.4    4    1    4    2    4    3
```

In the end there is just one dimension missing, but I don't want to use another iterator since the third dimension is already given by the vector I get back in every step.

Comment: rbind is binding all the outputs into a two dimensional matrix.  using rbind and cbind is limited to two specific dimensions. Check the package `abind` which lets you do an nth dimension equivalent.

Comment: The problem I have with abind using it for the 3rd dimension is that I need the iterators i and j for dimension 1 and 2. For the third dimension I do not have an explicit iterator, because I get it kind of implicitly as vector. If I use the abind (dimension 3) in the foreach loop with i or j, the output dimension still isn't the way I need it to be.